# JRuby supports utf-8?

Tags: ruby, jruby

When using JRuby 1.6.0.RC2 irb.  the Chinese character were not display correctly.

---

160: jruby 1.6.0.RC2 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 330) (2011-02-09 5434c72) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_23) [Windows XP-x86-java]

PS C:> irb
irb(main):001:0> puts "你好"

禮A礎n

=> nil

---

However, same terminal and switch to Ruby 1.9.2 using pik, the Chinese character were displayed just fine.

---

PS C:> pik 192

PS C:> irb

irb(main):001:0> puts "你好"

你好

=> nil

irb(main):002:0> puts RUBY_VERSION

1.9.2

=> nil

irb(main):003:0>

---

Since JRuby claims it can support UTF-8, am I doing something wrong or is it simply not ready yet?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a readline issue; do these work?

```
jruby -e 'puts "你好"'
jruby --1.9 -e 'puts "你好"'
jruby -Ku -e 'puts "你好"'
```

Comment: E:\jruby_i18n>jruby -e 'puts "你好"'

??

E:\jruby_i18n>jruby --1.9 -e 'puts "你好"'

??

E:\jruby_i18n>jruby -Ku -e 'puts "你好"'

??

All 3 produce the same "??" as output.

Comment: Ok, how about `jruby -e 'puts "你好"' > o.txt` and open o.txt in a text editor. I strongly suspect the problem is with your terminal.

Comment: same result.  Perhaps you are right.  However, **using the same terminal**, I can't explain why it works using Ruby 1.9.2 and not JRuby 1.6